# How to extract the value from nested array or nested object or similar condition in JSON using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting a result in JSON format where object can be inside array, object inside object or similar type of scenario. How to extract any specific value which might be inside an array or object or same using JQuery.

Below is the example of JSON which is stored in the variable result.

```
var result= {
  "to_station": {
    "name": "ANAND VIHAR TERMINAL",
    "lat": 28.6118176,
    "lng": 77.2888291,
    "code": "ANVT"
  },
  "train": {
    "name": "VIKRAMSHILA EXP",
    "classes": [
      {
        "name": "3rd AC ECONOMY",
        "available": "N",
        "code": "3E"
      },
      {
        "name": "FIRST CLASS",
        "available": "N",
        "code": "FC"
      },
      {
        "name": "FIRST AC",
        "available": "Y",
        "code": "1A"
      },
      {
        "name": "SECOND AC",
        "available": "Y",
        "code": "2A"
      },
      {
        "name": "SECOND SEATING",
        "available": "N",
        "code": "2S"
      },
      {
        "name": "AC CHAIR CAR",
        "available": "N",
        "code": "CC"
      },
      {
        "name": "SLEEPER CLASS",
        "available": "Y",
        "code": "SL"
      },
      {
        "name": "THIRD AC",
        "available": "Y",
        "code": "3A"
      }
    ],
    "days": [
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "MON"
      },
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "TUE"
      },
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "WED"
      },
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "THU"
      },
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "FRI"
      },
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "SAT"
      },
      {
        "runs": "Y",
        "code": "SUN"
      }
    ],
    "number": "12367"
  },
  "from_station": {
    "name": "BHAGALPUR",
    "lat": 25.2494829,
    "lng": 86.9828131,
    "code": "BGP"
  },
  "quota": {
    "name": "GENERAL QUOTA",
    "code": "GN"
  },
  "availability": [
    {
      "status": "GNWL37/WL24",
      "date": "25-8-2018"
    },
    {
      "status": "GNWL17/WL10",
      "date": "26-8-2018"
    },
    {
      "status": "GNWL14/WL11",
      "date": "27-8-2018"
    },
    {
      "status": "GNWL3/RAC19",
      "date": "28-8-2018"
    },
    {
      "status": "RAC   9/RAC   7",
      "date": "29-8-2018"
    },
    {
      "status": "AVAILABLE-0017",
      "date": "30-8-2018"
    }
  ],
  "debit": 3,
  "response_code": 200,
  "journey_class": {
    "name": "THIRD AC",
    "code": "3A"
  }
}
```

Suppose I want to extract the status (inside availability) for all the resulted date, how should I do the same using JQuery.

Comment: What is the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: here availability and status both are dynamic or only status ?

Comment: availability is static and status value gets changes as per the scenario.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I am new to JSON, though I am using $each function to loop through the array. But the result is not coming as expected. I require to show status for all the date from the given JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following if using jQuery:

```
$.each(result.availability, function(idx, data){
    //status is available as data.status
    console.log(data.date + ' ' + data.status);
});
```

You could also achieve the same with plain javascript:

```
for(var idx in result.availability){
    //status is available as result.availability[idx].status
    console.log(result.availability[idx].date + ' ' + result.availability[idx].status);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What if I want to access object inside object.

Comment: could you explain?